# How do I get my C# program to sleep for 50 milliseconds?

Tags: c#, vb.net

How do I get my C# program to sleep (pause execution) for 50 milliseconds?

Comment: If I were on the VB.Net team, I'd add ; as a comment character to the next version of the language...

Comment: I think VB programmers are bright enough to figure out the equivalent..

Answer (score 418, accepted):

```
System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(50);
```

Remember though, that doing this in the main GUI thread will block your GUI from updating (it will feel "sluggish")

Just remove the `;` to make it work for VB.net as well.

Comment: After calling sleep in a method, will the program continue to execute in the background(without creating new thread)? Also, if i call sleep in a new thread, will the main thread continue its work?

Comment: @JayNirgudkar the thread that calls Sleep will be stopped. Other threads are not affected.

Comment: This is not guaranteed to be accurate.

Answer (score 175):

There are basically 3 choices for waiting in (almost) any programming language:

1. **Loose waiting**

   - Executing thread blocks for given time (= does not consume processing power)
   - No processing is possible on blocked/waiting thread
   - Not so precise
2. **Tight waiting** (also called tight loop)

   - processor is VERY busy for the entire waiting interval (in fact, it usually consumes 100% of one core's processing time)
   - Some actions can be performed while waiting
   - Very precise
3. **Combination** of previous 2

   - It usually combines processing efficiency of 1. and preciseness + ability to do something of 2.

---

**for 1. - Loose waiting in C#:**

```
Thread.Sleep(numberOfMilliseconds);
```

However, windows thread scheduler causes acccuracy of `Sleep()` to be around 15ms (so Sleep can easily wait for 20ms, even if scheduled to wait just for 1ms).

**for 2. - Tight waiting in C# is:**

```
Stopwatch stopwatch = Stopwatch.StartNew();
while (true)
{
    //some other processing to do possible
    if (stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds >= millisecondsToWait)
    {
        break;
    }
}
```

We could also use `DateTime.Now` or other means of time measurement, but `Stopwatch` is much faster (and this would really become visible in tight loop).

**for 3. - Combination:**

```
Stopwatch stopwatch = Stopwatch.StartNew();
while (true)
{
    //some other processing to do STILL POSSIBLE
    if (stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds >= millisecondsToWait)
    {
        break;
    }
    Thread.Sleep(1); //so processor can rest for a while
}
```

This code regularly blocks thread for 1ms (or slightly more, depending on OS thread scheduling), so processor is not busy for that time of blocking and code does not consume 100% of processor's power. Other processing can still be performed in-between blocking (such as: updating of UI, handling of events or doing interaction/communication stuff).

Comment: [Timer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) may also be of interest

Answer (score 56):

You can't specify an *exact* sleep time in Windows.  You need a real-time OS for that.  The best you can do is specify a *minimum* sleep time.  Then it's up to the scheduler to wake up your thread after that.  And **never** call `.Sleep()` on the GUI thread.

Answer (score 56):

Since now you have async/await feature, the best way to sleep for 50ms is by using Task.Delay:

```
async void foo()
{
    // something
    await Task.Delay(50);
}
```

Or if you are targeting .NET 4 (with Async CTP 3 for VS2010 or Microsoft.Bcl.Async), you must use:

```
async void foo()
{
    // something
    await TaskEx.Delay(50);
}
```

This way you won't block UI thread.

Comment: can you response.flush during this delay, if it is in a loop?

Comment: No, you cannot. I believe there is a `FlushAsync` version.

Comment: An alternative which doesn't require an `async` declaration is to call `Task.Delay(50).Wait();`

Comment: Suggestion to use `Wait` should be followed only with extreme caution due to potential deadlocks when blocking on async operations.

Answer (score 32):

Use this code

```
using System.Threading;
// ...
Thread.Sleep(50);
```

Answer (score 14):

```
Thread.Sleep(50);
```

The thread will not be scheduled for execution by the operating system for the amount of time specified. This method changes the state of the thread to include WaitSleepJoin.

This method does not perform standard COM and SendMessage pumping. 
If you need to sleep on a thread that has STAThreadAttribute, but you want to perform standard COM and SendMessage pumping, consider using one of the overloads of the Join method that specifies a timeout interval.

```
Thread.Join
```

Answer (score 8):

For readability:

```
using System.Threading;
Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(50));
```

Answer (score 1):

Starting with .NET Framework 4.5, you can use:

```
using System.Threading.Tasks;

Task.Delay(50).Wait();   // wait 50ms
```

Comment: Posted [6 years prior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/91108/how-do-i-get-my-c-sharp-program-to-sleep-for-50-msec/57364499#comment31219736_13684964).

Comment: Blocking on async operations is potentially dangerous and may lead to deadlocks.  Use with extreme caution.

Answer (score 0):

In C#, you can make your program pause for a specified number of milliseconds using the Thread.Sleep method or Task.Delay. Here are examples of how to do this:

```
using System;
using System.Threading;

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        // Sleep for 50 milliseconds
        Thread.Sleep(50);
    Console.WriteLine("Sleep for 50 milliseconds");
    }
}
```

Using Task.Delay (asynchronous approach):

```
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

class Program
{
    static async Task Main()
    {
        // Sleep for 50 milliseconds asynchronously
        await Task.Delay(50);
        
        // pause for 50 milliseconds and then continue execution.
        Console.WriteLine("resumed after sleeping for 50 ms.");
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Best of both worlds:

```
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

    [DllImport("winmm.dll", EntryPoint = "timeBeginPeriod", SetLastError = true)]
    private static extern uint TimeBeginPeriod(uint uMilliseconds);

    [DllImport("winmm.dll", EntryPoint = "timeEndPeriod", SetLastError = true)]
    private static extern uint TimeEndPeriod(uint uMilliseconds);
    /**
     * Extremely accurate sleep is needed here to maintain performance so system resolution time is increased
     */
    private void accurateSleep(int milliseconds)
    {
        //Increase timer resolution from 20 miliseconds to 1 milisecond
        TimeBeginPeriod(1);
        Stopwatch stopwatch = new Stopwatch();//Makes use of QueryPerformanceCounter WIN32 API
        stopwatch.Start();

        while (stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds < milliseconds)
        {
            //So we don't burn cpu cycles
            if ((milliseconds - stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds) > 20)
            {
                Thread.Sleep(5);
            }
            else
            {
                Thread.Sleep(1);
            }
        }

        stopwatch.Stop();
        //Set it back to normal.
        TimeEndPeriod(1);
    }
```