# How can I stop/delay the code for a few seconds?

Tags: asp.net

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [How do I get my C# program to sleep for 50 msec?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/91108/how-do-i-get-my-c-program-to-sleep-for-50-msec)

Is there any Delay() or sleep() in ASP.net to stop the application for some time?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 37):

```
System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(numberOfMilisecondsToSleep)
```

See the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d00bd51t.aspx) for further details. Generally, this isn't something you would have to do in an ASP.NET application very frequently. It will just make the request seem slower.