# Call Server.Transfer after x seconds of page load in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to load page2.aspx 10 seconds after page1.aspx loads. This is my code. All help appreciated.

```
namespace test
{   
public partial class page1 : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Server.Transfer("page2.aspx");
    }
}
}
```

I want page1 to show for 10 seconds and then load page 2. I cannot use thread.sleep because it does not load the page at all.

Comment: Add a `Thread.Sleep()` before the transfer. But, that will not load page1 at all, it'll just wait for some time and go to page 2.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I get my C# program to sleep for 50 msec?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/91108/how-do-i-get-my-c-sharp-program-to-sleep-for-50-msec)

Comment: I cannot use thread.sleep because it does not load the page at all.

Comment: Another simple way would to add timer and intialize and start timer on page prerender event and handle timer elapsed event and do server.transfer

Comment: It'd be interesting to know what exactly you are trying to achieve. Show a page for few seconds, then suddenly load another page! Depending on what you need, it might be just a popup, or client side redirect or something else.

Comment: nobody didn't cancelled *meta refresh* tag. Add next code to your head tag: <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="10;URL=Page2.aspx">

Comment: @Viru how exactly can I do it.? Can you please help.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nobody cancelled `refresh` meta tag. Add following to your *head*:

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="10;URL=Page2.aspx" />
```

Posted my comment as answer

Comment: It would refresh the page. I dont want to do that.

Comment: @nick It will send you to Page2.aspx 10 seconds later. Just try this, and you will see, that this is correct.

Comment: @Nick but it is your choice. It's a simple code that will give you what you need. If you will use timers, so on, you have to do many steps instead of such a simple solution.