# Delay a timer once

Tags: c#, timer, delay

I'm working on a project which needs to do something every 24h. I have a timer for that, but when i start the program i want it to delay the timer once så im sure it runs during the night.

The timer :

```
timeForFitbitUpdate = 86400000; // Setting 24 hours of intervals
Timer aTimer = new Timer(10);
aTimer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(RunEvent);
aTimer.Interval = timeForFitbitUpdate;
aTimer.Enabled = true;
```

I have tried this code:

```
int delayTime = CalculateDelay();
var connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["VRT"].ConnectionString;
FitbitDataSave dataSave = new FitbitDataSave(connectionString);
await Task.Delay(delayTime);
dataSave.DoTimedWork();
```

but with other hardcoded miliseconds both in timer and the delay..
The delay was set to 5 minutes and timer to 5 minutes and it took the first time 10 minutes and after that 11 minutes and so on..

If any one have any ideas pls share thnx :)

Comment: You can use task to delay the start of the timer like : `Task.Factory.StartNew( () => { Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch(); sw.Start(); while(sw.ElapsedMilliseconds != delayTime){} aTimer.Enabled = true; });`

Comment: @m.rogalski, please don't recommend CPU intensive polling (or polling at all), we have `Task.Delay()`/`Thread.Sleep()` for this (see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5743843/1997232) answer).

Comment: @Sinatr It;s up to him which method he will use to wait for delay. I'm just giving simpliest and readable example

Comment: If it is something that must be done once a day, i would go with a scheduled task...

Answer (score 0):

I would probably set your interval to CalculateDelay(); on start-up.

Then as part of your ElapsedEventHandler, change your interval to your 24 hour setting.