# Delay an operation within a while loop in ASP.NET (async)

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, windows, loops

I need to create a while loop with 10 seconds of delay between each iteration:

```
while (true)
{
    // operation
    // delay for 10 seconds
}
```

Comment: Did you consider a Timer instead?

Comment: @Steve Yes, I really tried using a timer, but I didn’t succeed. Can you explain how to use it, please.

Comment: if you're in a context that allows `async` add `await Task.Delay(10000);`.

Comment: @TobiasTengler Ty very much

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I get my C# program to sleep for 50 msec?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/91108/how-do-i-get-my-c-sharp-program-to-sleep-for-50-msec)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could use [`Task.Delay`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.delay) for this:

```
var timespan = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10); 

await Task.Delay(timespan);

// or

Task.Delay(timespan).Wait();
```

I'm recommending this over `Thread.Sleep`, since `Thread.Sleep` blocks your entire Thread while waiting, whilst `Task.Delay` allows the Thread to deal with other work, while waiting.

Answer (score 0):

Just insert a sleep timer inside the while loop that sleeps for 10 seconds.

See this thread: [How do I get my C# program to sleep for 50 msec?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/91108/how-do-i-get-my-c-sharp-program-to-sleep-for-50-msec)