# I need the python time.sleep() equivalent in c#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I need to pause some code in an if statement in c#. Thread.Sleep() is NOT what I want as it pauses everything. I just want to temporarily hold the code in an if statement where it is for a few seconds.

I have tried Thread.Sleep() but it is not what I want.

This is in my Update() method.

```cs
if (jumps == jumpsToFatigue)
    {
        // wait for jumpFatigueWait (variable that is in seconds)
        jumps = 0f;
    }
```

I want something that can replace the comment that will pause THIS if statement ONLY for the time specified in my variable.

Comment: Task.Delay(jumpsToFatigue*1000)

Comment: I get an error saying task does not exist in current context

Comment: Thread.Sleep only pauses the current thread, it does NOT pause "everything".

Comment: Have a look at this post, might help you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/91108/how-do-i-get-my-c-sharp-program-to-sleep-for-50-msec

Comment: Thread.sleep pauses my player mid-jump...

Comment: @FinHarris You need to put `using System.Threading.Tasks;` at the top of the page so you have the library for the `Task` class

Comment: rishabh_batra I looked at that but it is not what I am looking for

Comment: If Thread.Sleep pauses your player animation, then your if statement is on the same thread as your player animation. You need to run your if statement on a different thread to the animation, which you can do using a Task.

Comment: `but it is not what I am looking for` You need to be clearer as to **why** this is not what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry cant test now but you can try,Edited

```
   IEnumerator WaitForYourSecond()
    {
      yield return new WaitForSeconds(2f);
      jump = 0;
    }
    void Update()
    {
    if (jumps == jumpsToFatigue)
        {
           StartCoroutine("WaitForYourSecond");

        }
    }
```

Comment: You'll probably want another check for if the coroutine is already running, or hitting the fatigue limit will let you spam the control and get as many jumps as you want for 2 seconds after the cooldown expires.